# GWT FileUpload - Set the response Content-Type through Client code

Tags: javascript, gwt, dom-events, gwt-rpc, asyncfileupload

I have a file upload form in GWT and the upload process works fine. Though, I have problem getting the response. The response capturing code is:

```
formUpload.addSubmitCompleteHandler(new FormPanel.SubmitCompleteHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onSubmitComplete(final SubmitCompleteEvent event) {
        fileUploadControl.handleResponse(htmlToText(event.getResults()));
    }
});
```

The `event.getResults()` always results in `null`. Upon investigating, I found that the response `Content-Type` should be one of `text/html` or `text/plain`. In my case, it is `application/xml` and I can't control the server response as well.

I was wondering if it is possible to set `Accept` request header in file upload form. If it is not possible, any other suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> See documentation [SubmitCompleteEvent#getResults](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FormPanel.SubmitCompleteEvent.html#getResults%28%29)
>
> `public java.lang.String getResults()` Gets the result text of the form
>   submission. 
> **Returns:** 
>      the result html, or null if there was an error
>   reading it 
> **Tip:**
>  The result html can be null as a result of submitting
>   a form to a different domain.

If It is working without errors, maybe domains are different.

Comment: Its the same domain, and yes - event.getResults() returns null. Is there any other suggestion ("accept" request header in form submit, parsing the iframe result, etc.?)